# Is there an English word meaning "the use of uncommon words"?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

Is there an English word meaning "the use of uncommon words" or similar?

Answer (score 18):

It depends on what you mean by "uncommon". [*Lexiphanicism*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/lexiphanicism) is the use of excessive terminology, while [*patavinity*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/patavinity) is the use of local or provincial words.

(I hope you are not just looking for *slang* or *jargon*.)

Comment: Thank you, thank you for telling me about lexiphanicism.  What a beautiful word.  I'll keep it on my desktop, and wait for an opportunity to use it.

Answer (score 8):

In the category of similar words, there's [*sesquipedalian*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sesquipedalian), meaning prone to using long words.

Answer (score 4):

If the uncommon words are being used specifically to obscure meaning, then "obfuscation" might apply.

Comment: Obfuscation could be achieved with uncommon use of common words as well.

Answer (score 1):

*Obscurantist* is related to the 'obfuscation' direction of your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean use of words or meanings that are outdated, you might be looking for [*archaic*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/archaic).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how and why you want to use it, [*logorrhea*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logorrhea_%28psychology%29) (also spelled *logorrhoea*) might do the trick. It doesn't specifically mean using uncommon words but either *a.* excessive verbosity generally or *b.* a psychological disorder resulting in incoherent talkativeness.

As an added bonus it conjures up a little hint of a certain other word ending *-rrhea*.

Answer (score 0):

**Esoteric Writing**

[**Esoteric**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/esoteric) (merriam-webster)
1 a : designed for or understood by the specially initiated alone
*a body of esoteric legal doctrine — B. N. Cardozo*
b : requiring or exhibiting knowledge that is restricted to a small group
*esoteric terminology*;
**broadly : difficult to understand *esoteric subjects***

**[esoteric](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/esoteric)** (wiktionary)
1. Understood only by a chosen few or an enlightened inner circle.
*The writing in this manual is very **esoteric**; I need a degree in engineering just to understand it!*

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you mean using uncommon words in a pompous way: pontification. To express your opinion in a pompous or dogmatic way.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! This answer would be improved by citing an external source with the definition of this word.

Answer (score 0):

The prior answers appertain to the question more precisely, but I think in the right context, a word such as "**ponderous**," meaning *laborious, dull, and excessively detailed*, might be suitable;  It also carries a more literary connotation than *loquacious* or *garrulous*, which describe speaking with superabundant wordiness, droning on, or talking in a roundabout manner.