# English word that means the use of out of place uncommon words

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word or short phrase that best describes a scenario in which an author seems to have copiously placed uncommon or higher educated vocabulary in a lower reading level book. Meaning that the book seems to be for a fourth grade reading level and then every few paragraphs an English Doctorate level word appears, possibly to impress readers.

Comment: There's *lexiphanic*, which is using pretentious wording or language, but it doesn't have the sense of intermittence you wanted.

Comment: @Martha: Oh, *juicy* word.  Thank you for improving my life.  I especially love that its usage is almost inescapably autological. :)

Comment: It's not a direct answer - but *anachronistic* could be a nice fit. Depends if the word(s) are still in common usage and/or you're referring to the usage pejoratively. Another pejorative choice would be *pedantically*. *Lexiphanic* is fantastic - I can't wait to use it :)

Comment: @Martha: In the comments on my answer, it turns out that *lexiphanic* is exactly what OP was looking for.  You should write your comment as an answer so it can get upvoted and accepted. :)

Comment: @chaos: posted an answer as requested.

Comment: Related: [Word meaning “use of uncommon words”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4659/)

Comment: @RegDwight: I think the difference is that this question asked for a word with negative connotations, while the other question wants a word with neutral connotations. (And has not yet received a satisfactory answer.)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

<sup>*[As requested, posting this as an answer instead of a comment]*</sup>

There's [*lexiphanic*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/lexiphanic), which is using pretentious wording or language, but it doesn't have the sense of intermittence you wanted.

(I found the word by plugging "using long words" into a [reverse dictionary](http://www.onelook.com/reverse-dictionary.shtml). The first two results, [*sesquipedalian*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sesquipedalian) and [*sesquipedality*](http://www.freedictionary.org/?Query=sesquipedality), are also good, but they don't necessarily have a negative connotation like *lexiphanic*.)

Comment: Almost any usage of "lexiphanic" would be lexiphanic. :)

Answer (score 3):

I nominate *erudition spikes*.

Visualize a chart with the book's erudition level on the Y axis, time or position on the X axis.  These sudden intrusions of sesquipedalian loquacity will appear as spikes on the graph.

Comment: Would it still fit if the words weren't long, just uncommon enough for an avid reader to have to look up?

Comment: @Rochelle: Sure.  Erudition is about education level, not word length.  I used "sesquipedalian" just to be cute. :)

Comment: I know that this particular author has a degree in English. However, the saga she has written seems to be for a less learned group of readers. I am just trying to pinpoint a more compact description for her use of more learned level vocabulary that seems out of place in this set of books.

Comment: Basically, I am a college student that has the brain wracking task of writing a college level paper about the middle school level, Twilight series.

Comment: @Rochelle: Makes sense.  It's complicated by the fact that most of the words we have for this sort of thing implicitly accuse the writer of pretentiousness, where it sounds as if the more likely motivation is pedagogical (as with Tolkien).  I tried to formulate a term that would be neutral as to motivation.

Comment: @Rochelle: Oh, if we're talking about Stephenie Meyer then I would definitely support the use of *lexiphanic* or *fustian*.

Comment: I looked up lexiphanic. That's it! Now I can complete my paper and stop wracking my poor little brain. Thank you for taking the time to help me out.

Comment: @Rochelle: You're welcome, but thank Martha; she's the one who just introduced me to that word, in the comments on your question. :)  I wish she'd written an answer rather than a comment, so she could get proper credit.

Comment: Though, fustian describes the style of teaching that this particular professor adheres to.

Comment: Thank you Martha. I appreciate your brain and your time.

Comment: @Rochelle: No reason you can't use both. :)  I mean, what's more fun than calling the Twilight Saga a turgid mass of lexiphanic fustian?

Comment: I wonder if my professor would get the irony if my low grade paper had such high level verbage?:)

Comment: @Rochelle: That's what I love about the word *lexiphanic*; it can hardly be used without being pretentious, and therefore making one's work itself lexiphanic.  Mmm, like me some autological words. :)

Comment: "Despite her best efforts, the book oozes erudition" :)

Answer (score 3):

More specifically,

the word is "Grandiloquent", if the writer has a tendency to use grand words, instead of common ones;

or

"Magniloquent", if the writer has a tendency to use long/large words, instead of short/small ones

Answer (score 1):

Circumlocutious/circumlocutory are the words you are looking for.

M-w.com defines circumlocution (of which the above words are adjectival forms,)  as :

1
: the use of an unnecessarily large number of words to express an idea
2
: evasion in speech

Comment: For the benefit of the OP and fellow ELU members, please provide a reference source and definition in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would tend to use *uncromulent*.

Comment: Tee hee! Thank you for embiggening our vocabulary! :)

Answer (score 0):

ostentation - Ambitious display; pretentious parade; vain show; display intended to excite admiration or applause; A show or spectacle

sententious - excessive moralizing

Answer (score -1):

That was one of J.R.R. Tolkien's strategies in writing for children.  He thought that by inserting bits of higher-level phrases and vocabulary, children would learn more from reading.

So, to invent a word, I suggest using 'Tolkienesque'.

Comment: It's taken, unfortunately.  Means epic high fantasy with elves and dwarves (as opposed to dwarfs) and whatnot, more or less.

Comment: I am new to this site but if you can tell me how to give credit to Martha I would be more than happy to after I get out of class.

Comment: Just click on the UP arrow over the number to the left of her post. That said, "Intermittent anomalous vocabulation" is often a poor teaching technique. Woggle-Bug in the Oz books used it extensively. He was not well liked.

Answer (score -1):

You might also consider *[euphuistic](http://www.google.com/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=definition%3a+euphuistic)*.

Comment: `Elaborate alliteration, antitheses, and similes`?  Not sure I get the correlation.  http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Euphuistic

Comment: @vapcguy: When I answered this question 4 years ago there was a different title and different content. It was about high-sounding words, not simply something being "out of place."

Comment: There, I rolled it back. Read the text of the question and you'll see that bears it out.

Comment: Uncommon or not - that wasn't my issue with `euphuistic`. I found it's meaning doesn't have anything to do with being `out-of-place`.

Comment: Read the text of the question, not the title. OP just expressed himself poorly..

Comment: I would suggest you should do the same.  Part of the question reads:  `an author seems to have copiously placed uncommon or higher educated vocabulary in a lower reading level book` -- anything where a word of one type ("higher educated vocabulary") is intermingled with the another type ("lower...level") means it is out-of-place, just like the title of the question says. Nothing about alliteration, similies, and grammatical plays of words on each other.

Answer (score -1):

*[Saltation](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/saltation)*, from the Latin *saltus* (“to leap”) has senses including "any abrupt transition", "a light springing movement upwards or forwards", "the leaping movement of sand or soil particles [transported] over an uneven surface", "a mutation that drastically changes the phenotype of an organism or species".  It might be used figuratively to indicate uneven or untoward wording: "Her vocabulary's saltation was alarming."

Answer (score -1):

I'd use eccentric:

Departing from a recognized, conventional, or established norm or pattern.

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/eccentric

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain?